# How do I make Google Sheets ignore my data in certain cells?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet that demonstrates my problem. Feel free to edit it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kkGTTOUNSZDDRMRaZdxKJrbWdP2HsYVrpEyTRr1R508/edit?usp=sharing

In cell B1, the value I am trying to scrape is there. However, data below B1 (all the way to B31) is shown and I don't want it to exist on my sheet. How can I get rid of it? Column A is an example of how I would want to paste the scraped value "18.39" in a previously existing list.

Answer (score 1):

Add a +-sign before your formula. This will limit the output to the first value of the array.

```
=+importxml("https://www.fantasysp.com/nba_player_news/Willie_Cauley-Stein/", "//td[7]")
```

An alternative method would be to use INDEX()

```
=index(importxml("https://www.fantasysp.com/nba_player_news/Willie_Cauley-Stein/", "//td[7]"), 1, 1)
```